# strace -p with number of lines of context/history

Tags: strace

I'd like to `strace` a running process, which I know I can do with `strace -p <pid>`, but I believe the process has hung on some blocking call, e.g. `sem_wait()` on a semaphore that's never posted, etc., and the output of `strace` is only one line, like:

```
Process 195 attached - interrupt to quit
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}], 2, 3600000^C <unfinished ...>
```

Is it possible to specify `strace` to output more lines of context/history? I'm guessing not, because I'm guessing `strace` ouputs realtime and per function/instruction, but I thought I'd ask to confirm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, there is no history available.

In case it is not obvious, the output shows that the process is in a `poll` call, waiting for input from file descriptors 3 and 6. Running `ls -l /proc/195/fd` should show what these descriptors are connected to.

Answer (score 6):

You can also attach to a process with `gdb`, and see the current stack, for example, which may help, especially if you have compiled your program with debugging symbols you will have more information.

As an example, run `sleep` in the background, get its pid and run gdb with the pid and the object file, then give the command `bt` for backtrace. To continue the program type `detach`.

```
$ sleep 999 & 
[1] 17340
$ gdb -p 17340 /bin/sleep 
Reading symbols from /bin/sleep...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Attaching to program: /usr/bin/sleep, process 17340
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install coreutils-8.24-8.fc23.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fb84f43d510 in __nanosleep_nocancel () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000562be81da29f in rpl_nanosleep ()
#2  0x0000562be81da100 in xnanosleep ()
#3  0x0000562be81d7a1d in main ()
(gdb) detach
Detaching from program: /usr/bin/sleep, process 17340
(gdb) quit
```